# What is the way to get group members from the SID of a group?

Tags: c, active-directory, openldap

I have the SID string of a user/group in a Microsoft AD server. Now from this SID string, is it possible to check if it belongs to a user or a group, and if it is a group, get the members of the group ?

From whatever I could search for, I could get only the reverse; i.e., all the groups that a member belongs to. But what I need is a way to get all the members of a given group (whose SID is known).

Edit: I am using openldap on Linux to talk with the AD server btw.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following work? Lookup the user by `objectsid` and then look at the `"memberof`" field.

```
ldapsearch -vvv -h <ad-server> -p <port>  -D <bindn> -w <passwd> -b  <basedn> "objectSid=<sid>" memberOf
```

If you have the SID of the group, you can lookup the group based on `objectsid` and then look at the `"member`" field

```
ldapsearch -vvv -h <ad-server> -p <port>  -D <bindn> -w <passwd> -b  <basedn> "objectSid=<sid>" member
```